# How can I speed up unzipping / reading files with a mounted Google Drive in Colab?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm using Colab with a mounted Google Drive to unpack zips and consolidate the csvs that come out of them. But this, for example:

```
for z in zip_list:
    zipfile.ZipFile(z, 'r').extractall()
    zipfile.ZipFile(z, 'r').close()
    os.remove(z)
```

runs about 60x slower in Colab/Drive compared to when I run it on my local computer. Why is this so much slower and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there any potential network latency involved? What are the specs of the environment this is running under? I'm not familiar with the drive API or colaboraty, but network latency & difference in environment are general cases for different results on different machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical strategy is to copy the .zip file from Drive to the local disk first.

Unzipping involves lots of small operations like file creation, which are much faster on a local disk than Drive, which is remote.